# How can I eliminate the need of the command 'python' when running a python file in terminal?

Tags: python, bash, shell, python-2.7, command

I would like to run python files from terminal without having to use the command `$ python`. But I would still like to keep the ability of using `'$ python` to enter the python interpreter. For example if I had a file named 'foo.py', I can use `$ foo.py` rather than `$ python foo.py` to run the file.

How can I do this? Would I need to change the bash file or the paths? And is it possible to have both commands available, so I can use both `$ foo.py` and `$ python foo.py`?

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and my terminal/shell uses a '.bashrc' file. I have multiple versions of python installed on my computer, but when running a python file I want the default version to be the latest version of 2.7.x. If what I am asking is not possible or not recommended, I want to at least shorten the command `$ python` to `$ py`.

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you **can** do this.

1) Ensure that the first line in your file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

2) Ensure that your files have the execute permission bit set, like this:

```
$ chmod +x foo.py
```

3) Now, assuming that your `$PATH` environment variable is set correctly<sup>*</sup>, you can run `foo.py` either way:

```
$ foo.py
$ python foo.py
```

---

<sup>*</sup> By "correctly", I mean, "to include the directory where your python file lives." In the use case you describe, that probably means "to include the current directory". To do that, edit `.bashrc`. One possible line to put in `.bashrc` is: `PATH="$PATH":.`

Comment: So I would need to to add '#!/usr/bin/env python' at the top of all my python files? Is there a way around that or no?

Comment: You only need to include it on the ones you want to execute directly. You don't not need to include it on files that you `import`, for example. And the "way around that" is to say `python foo.py`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I apologize since I have done much in customizing my shell. The output that I get from `$ echo $PATH` is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`. Do you know if this path is set up correctly?

Comment: That `$PATH` does not include `.`. (Neither does mine, by the way. I hate having `.` in my `$PATH`.) So, you shold either add `.` to your `$PATH`, or invoke your program thus: `./foo.py`.

Comment: Is there any reason I shouldn't add `.` to `$PATH`? And btw thank you this is very helpful!

Comment: I leave it out of $PATH to avoid accidentally invoking a file that has the same name as a system program. Imagine if my cruel friends created a program called `ls` and secretly put it in a directory some where. Whenever I `cd /my/friends/directory` and typed `ls`, I'd get *their* program instead of the system one. In fact, my `.bashrc` is this: `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"`. That way, when my Python program evolves into something useful, I can copy it to `$HOME/bin` and make it always available to me, regardless of my current working directory.

Comment: Good reply & comments, Rob. But rather than copying my Python scripts to `$HOME/bin`, I prefer to make a (symbolic) link to them from my main Python sources directory.

Answer (score 0):

sharkbyte,

It's *easy* to insert '#!/usr/bin/env python' at the top of all your Python files. Just run this sed command in the directory where your Python files live:

`sed -i '1 i\#! /usr/bin/env python\n' *.py`

The `-i` option tells sed to do an in-place edit of the files, the `1` means operate only on line 1, and the `i\` is the insert command. I put a `\n` at the end of the insertion text to make the modified file look nicer. :)

If you're paranoid of stuffing up, copy some files to an empty directory first & do a test run.

Also, you can tell sed to make a backup of each original file, eg:

`sed -i.bak '1 i\#! /usr/bin/env python\n' *.py`

for MS style, or

`sed -i~ '1 i\#! /usr/bin/env python\n' *.py`

for the usual Linux style.